# Wordpress formats code incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

Why is wordpress code plugin showing the html code instead of decoding it, instead of doing a newline it render `<br/>`. I dont want that. My wordpress text looks like this

```
[code language="csharp"]
public class Foo    
{

}
[/code]
```

But its outputed like 
[image: Looks like crap]

Any idea why wordpress is doing this?

Its wordpress.com not selfhosting

Comment: May be you are adding code from `Editor -> visual`...
Try to add code from `Editor -> text`...
You can change editor view from top-right corner of editor...

Comment: Can I switch mode from blog editor?

Comment: Strange you get a less feature rich editor when you choose "New post". If you save draft and go into posts and open your post you get a more feature rich editor and in there it works as expected

Comment: Sometimes it happens...Don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to the functions.php :
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

This is a feature :D

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop